# C - How to restrict address access in heap?

Tags: c, pointers, static, heap-memory

For variables store in the stack, we can use `static` to avoid accessing from other files. Is there anyway to avoid pointer from other files accessing certain address?

Comment: Even with `static` it can still be accessed from other files via pointers :) Why do you need to *restrict* it anyway? Reduce the scope of the variable as much as possible and then don't pass around it if you don't want it to be accessed from elsewhere.

Comment: Perhaps only provide them with a pointer to something const. Static functions are not directly visible from other compilation utits. But if they have a pointer, to that region, they can read/write to/from that location or call the function.

Comment: I am writing an implementation, and want the program to throw something like an error when other files accidentally access some specific memory. So it could be easier to debug. @P.P.

Comment: The first problem you'd have to solve is how would such a system even know what is and isn't a proper access to any memory.

Comment: @YiLinLiu, there's no way to get an exception in your code for accessing another variable defined in other files.  The file a variable is defined on is lost in the linking phase of the program and you cannot restrict the access to your own memory (there's no operating system assistance to distinguish an access from your process to any virtual address of itself)

Answer (score 1):

First, to get things out of the way, static variables are never allocated on the stack because they are essentially global variables, they simply don't pollute the global namespace. It's trivial to get a pointer to a static variable and change it, statics are a compiler enforced construct.

Back to the actual question though, no you cannot try to examine the memory access directly. How would you even know if the memory you're accessing is valid or not? You can do something along the line though. You can for example, wrap malloc and free with your own memory management functions, and keep track of the memory allocated and freed along with metadata. You can then use another wrapper function that takes care of pointer dereferencing, and checks the metadata as you desire. You still can use raw pointers to wreak havoc if you want, so it isn't really much though.